# How to get a simple jQuery slideshow to work in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, slider, jsfiddle

Using the code from http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow, I have created a jsfiddle.

The problem is the slideshow is not working in the jsfiddle so I can't then adapt it for my needs

What could the problem be?

http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/8/

Code:

```
  function slideSwitch() {
            var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
        
            if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
        
            // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
            var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
                    
            $active.addClass('last-active');
        
            $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
        }
        
        $(function() {
            setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
        });
        
        </script>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
        /*** set the width and height to match your images **/
        
        #slideshow {
            position:relative;
            height:350px;
        }
        
        #slideshow IMG {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:8;
            opacity:0.0;
        }
        
        #slideshow IMG.active {
            z-index:10;
            opacity:1.0;
        }
        
        #slideshow IMG.last-active {
            z-index:9;
        }
        
        </style>
        
                
        <div id="slideshow">
          <img src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/simple-jquery-slideshow.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
          <img src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/mini-golf-ball.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
          <img src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/jon-raasch.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
          <img src="http://jonraasch.com/img/slideshow/ear-cleaning.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a problem in your code. You had extra parenthesis on the handler you've sent to [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

When sending handlers to functions, we don't write the parenthesis. If They're written, what actually happens is that the function (`slideSwitch()`) is called and its return value is being sent to the function (`setInterval`).

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000); // Not slideSwitch()
});
```

Now it's working

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UUKP4/10/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis from your `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
```

The first parameter of `setInterval` looks for a function to be run every  milliseconds. Rather than referencing the function, you're calling it. In your example, you're actually calling the function in the first parameter (and so as soon as your script loads). I'd imagine that your function returns `null` and so you don't get a JavaScript error, but simply `null` is run every 5000ms.